# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products"}, missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncontroller

I have a rSpec Controller test which fails

the index route will have an `:id` which does not exist in an index route.

I've clean routes:

`resources :products`

This is the controller,

```rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show]
  skip_before_action :authorize_request, only: [:show, :index]

  # GET /products
  def index
    # params here {"controller"=>"products", "action"=>"index", "product"=>{}}
    @products = Product.all

    render json: @products
  end
```

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {
:action=>"show", 
:controller=>"products"}, 
missing required keys: [:id]
```

Why is "show" called? I did not passed any params to the controller:
This is the spec:

```rb
RSpec.describe "/products", type: :request do

  describe " GET /index" do
    it " renders a successful response " do
      Fabricate.times(3, :product)
      get "/products", headers: valid_headers
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
end
```

When I change the routes from `get "/products", to: 'products#index'` and comment out `resources :products` then it passes the test

**EDIT / PROBLEM FOUND :**

I use `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in my Product model, which caused this issue. I need it to generate URLs to retrieve my attachments. How else can I get the URLs of `ActiveStorage` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem: I had `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in my Product model which caused the problem:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 # include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

commented out, all specs are passing now

But I still don't understand why I can't use it in my Model.

I wanna have it included to retrieve urls of my attachments:

```
  def main_image_thumb_url
    rails_blob_url(main_image, host: "localhost:3000")
  end
```